# svg!! change text on load

Tags: javascript, svg

Just wanted to ask is there any way of changing the svg text on load.
Standard SVG examples work just fine.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    document.getElementById('mySVGText').textContent = 'new_value';
});
```

it works on this svg

```
<svg version="1.1"  
baseProfile="full"  
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="mySVG">  

<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />  

<circle cx="150" cy="100" r="80" fill="green" />  

<text id="mySVGText" name="textName" x="150" y="125" font-size="60" text-anchor="middle" fill="white">SVG</text>
</svg>
```

but seems like this svg doesnt allow me to getElementById and change the text:

```
<svg version="1.1" 
id="Capa_1" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 489 489" 
 style="enable-background:new 0 0 489 489;" 
 xml:space="preserve"
 >

<text id="mySVGText" name="textName" x="160" y="400" font-size="280" text-anchor="middle" fill="blue">SVG</text>

<g>
<path style="fill:white" d="M440.1,422.7l-28-315.3c-0.6-7-6.5-12.3-13.4-12.3h-57.6C340.3,42.5,297.3,0,244.5,0s-95.8,42.5-96.6,95.1H90.3
    c-7,0-12.8,5.3-13.4,12.3l-28,315.3c0,0.4-0.1,0.8-0.1,1.2c0,35.9,32.9,65.1,73.4,65.1h244.6c40.5,0,73.4-29.2,73.4-65.1
    C440.2,423.5,440.2,423.1,440.1,422.7z M244.5,27c37.9,0,68.8,30.4,69.6,68.1H174.9C175.7,57.4,206.6,27,244.5,27z M366.8,462
    H122.2c-25.4,0-46-16.8-46.4-37.5l26.8-302.3h45.2v41c0,7.5,6,13.5,13.5,13.5s13.5-6,13.5-13.5v-41h139.3v41
    c0,7.5,6,13.5,13.5,13.5s13.5-6,13.5-13.5v-41h45.2l26.9,302.3C412.8,445.2,392.1,462,366.8,462z"/>

</g>

</svg>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: They both seem to be working for me. Are you sure you don't have another element with the id `mySVGText` on the same page? That might cause the  behavior you're seeing.

Comment: yep!! thanks Willaim. right on the money :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that this doesn't show up as unanswered:

The problem was that there were two elements with the id `mySVGText` on the page. `document.getElementById` assumes that each id on the page is unique, so it can have unexpected behavior when they aren't.